# How to escape a semicolon in Presto

Tags: escaping, presto

The data table is `testtable`:

```
col 

x;y

p;q

m;n
```

I've tried:

```
SELECT split(col,'\;') FROM testtable
SELECT split(col,'\\;') FROM testtable
SELECT split(col,'\;' ESCAPE '\') FROM testtable
```

to split the `col`, but none of codes above worked in Presto. Anyone knows how to escape the semicolon in Presto?

Answer (score 1):

You actually dont need to escape `;`

```
presto> SELECT split('aaa;bbb',';');
   _col0
------------
 [aaa, bbb]
(1 row)

presto> SELECT split('aaa;bbb',';')[1], split('aaa;bbb',';')[2];
 _col0 | _col1
-------+-------
 aaa   | bbb
(1 row)
```

if your intention is to have each entry as row, you ll need something like that (untested)

```
SELECT split_values
FROM testtable
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(SPLIT(col,';')) AS t (split_values)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  However, I think I still have to escape `;`  because I got the error message: `Statement ') FROM testtable is not supported`. Obviously, it treats `;` as the endpoint of the code and therefore throws the error saying  ')' is not supported.

Comment: Can you update your question with details about how this query is sent? (client/api..), based on your last comment, I suspect the issue to be more at that level